# insertSubView: is not showing my views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am stuck in a tutorial, trying to switch views with a toolbar. My code builds fine and I put some alerts in to check the toolbar was working, and it is. But my subviews I am inserting are just not showing up at all. Can anybody help please?

Here is my main controller code..

MainViewController.h is

```
#import 

@class FlavourPickerView;
@class ShakeView;
@class ResultsView;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet FlavourPickerView *flavourPickerView;
    IBOutlet ShakeView *shakeView;
    IBOutlet ResultsView *resultsView;
}

@property (retain,nonatomic) FlavourPickerView *flavourPickerView;
@property (retain,nonatomic) ShakeView *shakeView;
@property (retain,nonatomic) ResultsView *resultsView;

-(IBAction)loadFlavourPickerView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)loadShakeView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)loadResultsView:(id)sender;

-(void)clearView;

@end
```

and here is MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "FlavourPickerView.h"
#import "ShakeView.h"
#import "ResultsView.h"

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize flavourPickerView;
@synthesize shakeView;
@synthesize resultsView;


-(IBAction)loadFlavourPickerView:(id)sender{
 UIAlertView *alertDialog;
 alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
       initWithTitle:@"Flavour selected"
       message:@"Seems to work"
       delegate:nil
       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
       otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alertDialog show];
 [alertDialog release];

 [self clearView];
 [self.view insertSubview:flavourPickerView.view atIndex:10];
}


-(IBAction)loadShakeView:(id)sender{
 UIAlertView *alertDialog;
 alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
       initWithTitle:@"Shaker selected"
       message:@"Seems to work"
       delegate:nil
       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
       otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alertDialog show];
 [alertDialog release];

 [self clearView];
 [self.view insertSubview:shakeView.view atIndex:0];
}


-(IBAction)loadResultsView:(id)sender{
 UIAlertView *alertDialog;
 alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
       initWithTitle:@"Results selected"
       message:@"Seems to work"
       delegate:nil
       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
       otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alertDialog show];
 [alertDialog release];

 [self clearView];
 [self.view insertSubview:resultsView.view atIndex:0];

 }


-(void)clearView{
 if(flavourPickerView.view.superview){
  [flavourPickerView.view removeFromSuperview];
 }else if(shakeView.view.superview){
  [shakeView.view removeFromSuperview];
 }else{
  [resultsView.view removeFromSuperview];
 }
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [self loadFlavourPickerView:nil];
 [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [flavourPickerView release];
 [shakeView release];
 [resultsView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

and here is an example of one of the other views, starting with FlavourPickerView.h

```
#import 


@interface FlavourPickerView : UIViewController {

}

@end
```

and FlavourPickerView.m

```
#import "FlavourPickerView.h"


@implementation FlavourPickerView

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

There is also a nib for the flavourPickerView and I have added subviews into my mainView, with the Class set to FlavourPickerView and nib name is FlavourPickerView.xib.

Answer (score 1):

Are `flavourPickerView`, `shakeView`, and `resultsView` properly initialized when you add their view to this UIViewController view?
Another thing: avoid to call a UIViewController just 'XXXView', try instead 'XXXViewController'

Comment: Have added more code to the example above, and noted your valid point about XXXViewController, makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried to add the controller programmatically instead of using Interface Builder?